# Behavior of sleep and select in go

Tags: go, resources, sleep, blocking

I'm trying to understand a bit more about what happens under the surface during various blocking/waiting types of operations in Go. Take the following example:

```
otherChan = make(chan int)
t = time.NewTicker(time.Second)
for {
    doThings()

    // OPTION A: Sleep
    time.Sleep(time.Second)

    // OPTION B: Blocking ticker
    <- t.C

    // OPTION C: Select multiple
    select {
        case <- otherChan:
        case <- t.C:
    }
}
```

From a low level view (system calls, cpu scheduling) what is the difference between these while waiting?

My understanding is that `time.Sleep` leaves the CPU free to perform other tasks until the specified time has elapsed. Does the blocking ticker `<- t.C` do the same? Is the processor polling the channel or is there an interrupt involved? Does having multiple channels in a select change anything?

In other words, assuming that `otherChan` never had anything put into it, would these three options execute in an identical way, or would one be less resource intensive than the others?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

That's a very interesting question, so I did `cd` into my Go source to start looking.

### time.Sleep

`time.Sleep` is defined like this:

```
// src/time/sleep.go

// Sleep pauses the current goroutine for at least the duration d.
// A negative or zero duration causes Sleep to return immediately.
func Sleep(d Duration)
```

No body, no definition in an OS-specific `time_unix.go`!?! A little search and the answer is because `time.Sleep` is actually defined in the runtime:

```
// src/runtime/time.go

// timeSleep puts the current goroutine to sleep for at least ns nanoseconds.
//go:linkname timeSleep time.Sleep
func timeSleep(ns int64) {
  // ...
}
```

Which in retrospect makes a lot of sense, as it has to interact with the goroutine scheduler. It ends up calling `goparkunlock`, which "puts the goroutine into a waiting state". `time.Sleep` creates a `runtime.timer` with a callback function that is called when the timer expires - that callback function wakes up the goroutine by calling `goready`. See next section for more details on the `runtime.timer`.

### time.NewTicker

`time.NewTicker` creates a `*Ticker` (and `time.Tick` is a helper function that does the same thing but directly returns `*Ticker.C`, the ticker's receive channel, instead of `*Ticker`, so you could've written your code with it instead) has similar hooks into the runtime: a ticker is a struct that holds a `runtimeTimer` and a channel on which to signal the ticks.

`runtimeTimer` is defined in the `time` package but it must be kept in sync with `timer` in `src/runtime/time.go`, so it is effectively a `runtime.timer`. Remember that in `time.Sleep`, the timer had a callback function to wake up the sleeping goroutine? In the case of `*Ticker`, the timer's callback function sends the current time on the ticker's channel.

Then, the real waiting/scheduling happens on the receive from the channel, which is essentially the same as the `select` statement unless `otherChan` sends something before the tick, so let's look at what happens on a blocking receive.

### <- chan

Channels are implemented (now in Go!) in `src/runtime/chan.go`, by the `hchan` struct. Channel operations have matching functions, and a receive is implemented by `chanrecv`:

```
// chanrecv receives on channel c and writes the received data to ep.
// ep may be nil, in which case received data is ignored.
// If block == false and no elements are available, returns (false, false).
// Otherwise, if c is closed, zeros *ep and returns (true, false).
// Otherwise, fills in *ep with an element and returns (true, true).
func chanrecv(t *chantype, c *hchan, ep unsafe.Pointer, block bool) (selected, received bool) {
  // ...
}
```

This part has a lot of different cases, but in your example, it is a blocking receive from an asynchronous channel (`time.NewTicker` creates a channel with a buffer of 1), but anyway it ends up calling... `goparkunlock`, again to allow other goroutines to proceed while this one is stuck waiting.

### So...

In all cases, the goroutine ends up being parked (which is not really shocking - it can't make progress, so it has to leave its thread available for a different goroutine if there's any available). A glance at the code seems to suggest that the channel has a bit more overhead than a straight-up `time.Sleep`. However, it allows far more powerful patterns, such as the last one in your example: the goroutine can be woken up by another channel, whichever comes first.

To answer your other questions, regarding polling, the timers are managed by a goroutine that sleeps until the next timer in its queue, so it's working only when it knows a timer has to be triggered. When the next timer has expired, it wakes up the goroutine that called `time.Sleep` (or sends the value on the ticker's channel, it does whatever the callback function does).

There's no polling in channels, the receive is unlocked when a send is made on the channel, in `chansend` of the chan.go file:

```
// wake up a waiting receiver
sg := c.recvq.dequeue()
if sg != nil {
    recvg := sg.g
    unlock(&c.lock)
    if sg.releasetime != 0 {
        sg.releasetime = cputicks()
    }
    goready(recvg, 3)
} else {
    unlock(&c.lock)
}
```

That was an interesting dive into Go's source code, very interesting question! Hope I answered at least part of it!