# Where is the definition for `time.Sleep` defined in the go source code?

Tags: go

I looked into the [source](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.20.5:src/time/sleep.go;l=9) for `time.Sleep`. Found that there is just one line of declaration with no definition. I'm curious as to how it's actually working.

This is the only line is the source, which I couldn't wrap my head around.

```golang
func Sleep(d Duration)
```

So far I've looked into the source code, did some digging online. All links, explain how to use `time.Sleep` but not how it works, which is understandable.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32148983/11810946) answer your question? (question has a different focus but answer is spot on).

Comment: The implementation is [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/0b5a4afec9df67157891732e5ca660eaf1efab34/src/runtime/time.go#L175-L196).

Comment: Thank you both. How did you know where to look for this? Also, what is the mechanism that decides to run this definition. When `time.Sleep` is called? Is it just this `//go:linkname timeSleep time.Sleep`? Finally, why is it implemented this way?

Answer (score -1):

The source function is `timeSleep`

[Source code](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/0b5a4afec9df67157891732e5ca660eaf1efab34/src/runtime/time.go#L178)

Basically they maintain the timers in a heap. And call `gopark` on the running goroutine to put it into sleep(lock).